# Explain (.)(.) to me

Tags: haskell, pointfree

Diving into Haskell, and while I am enjoying the language I'm finding the pointfree style completely illegible. I've come a across this function which only consists of these ASCII boobies as seen below.

```
f = (.)(.)
```

And while I understand its type signature and what it does, I can't for the life of me understand why it does it. So could someone please write out the de-pointfreed version of it for me, and maybe step by step work back to the pointfree version sorta like this:

```
f g x y = (g x) + y   
f g x = (+) (g x)    
f g = (+) . g    
f = (.) (+)
```

Comment: Uhm.... should I tell him?

Comment: Have you tried actually expanding the implementation of `(.)` to see what this results in?

Comment: @Dai I'm sure he probably knows! 

Comment: "I'm finding the pointfree style completely illegible" - You and me both, friend! Anything more than a flat pipeline of `.`s and I'm lost. Everyone learning Haskell goes through a phase of trying to write everything point-free and then comes out the other side

Comment: How is `(.)(.)` formed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also gradually append arguments to `f`:

```
f = ((.) . )
f x = (.) . x
f x y = ((.) . x) y
      = (.) (x y)
      = ((x y) . )
f x y z = (x y) . z
f x y z t = ((x y) . z) t
          = (x y) (z t)
          = x y (z t)
          = x y $ z t
```

The result reveals that `x` and `z` are actually (binary and unary, respectively) functions, so I'll use different identifiers:

```
f g x h y = g x (h y)
```

Answer (score 18):

Generally `(?)` (where `?` stands for an arbitrary infix operator) is the same as `\x y -> x ? y`. So we can rewrite `f` as:

```
f = (\a b -> a . b) (\c d -> c . d)
```

Now if we apply the argument to the function, we get:

```
f = (\b -> (\c d -> c . d) . b)
```

Now `b` is just an argument to `f`, so we can rewrite this as:

```
f b = (\c d -> c . d) . b
```

The definition of `.` is `f . g = \x -> f (g x)`. If replace the outer `.` with its definition, we get:

```
f b = \x -> (\c d -> c . d) (b x)
```

Again we can turn `x` into a regular parameter:

```
f b x = (\c d -> c . d) (b x)
```

Now let's replace the other `.`:

```
f b x = (\c d y -> c (d y)) (b x)
```

Now let's apply the argument:

```
f b x = \d y -> (b x) (d y)
```

Now let's move the parameters again:

```
f b x d y = (b x) (d y)
```

Done.

Comment: Why does the `(\c d -> c . d)` replace the `a` and not the `b`? I though Haskell went from right to left.

Comment: @Erik `\a b -> ...` is short for `\a -> (\b -> ...)`. So you have a function that, when given an argument `a`, produces another function expecting an argument `b`. So `a` comes first. Or put differently: given `(\a b -> ...) 1 2`, `a` will be `1` and `b` will be `2`. So the left-most argument goes to the left-most parameter.

Answer (score 5):

We *can* work backwards by *"pattern matching"* over the combinators' definitions. Given

```
f a b c d =  a b  (c d) 
          = (a b) (c d)
```

we proceed

```
         = B (a b) c d 
         = B B a b c d    -- writing B for (.)
```

so by [eta-contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-conversion)

```
f = B B
```

because

```
a (b c) = B a b c         -- bidirectional equation
```

by definition. Haskell's `(.)` is actually the **B** combinator (see [BCKW combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,_C,_K,_W_system)).

---

*edit:* Potentially, many combinators can match the same code. That's why there are many possible combinatory encodings for the same piece of code. For example, `(ab)(cd) = (ab)(I(cd))` is a valid transformation, which might lead to some other combinator definition matching *that*. Choosing the "most appropriate" one is an art (or a search in a search space with somewhat high branching factor).

That's about going *backwards*, as you asked. But if you want to go "forward", personally, I like the combinatory approach much better over the lambda notation fidgeting. I would even just write many arguments right away, and get rid of the extra ones in the end:

```
BBabcdefg = B(ab)cdefg = (ab)(cd)efg
```

hence,

```
BBabcd    = B(ab)cd    = (ab)(cd)
```

is all there is to it.

Comment: I think this could really use some more background. It almost looks like it's written backwards.

Comment: @dfeuer well, the OP asked for "backwards"... seriously though, I've realized this after writing it, but decided it was short enough for a reader to follow (or equivalently, read it bottom to top). I also assumed/remembered that "eta-contraction" is easily googlable. what more background could it be?

Comment: What do you mean by "'pattern matching' over the combinator definitions"? That's what really threw me for a loop.

Comment: @dfeuer I've edited this to the asnwer, thanks for the discussion.